# Static IP address in Azure API management Service

Tags: azure, static-ip-address, azure-api-management

I have done some googling but couldn't get a confirmed answer for this: 
Does Azure API management service provides a Static IP address? If not, how do i configure it?

Reason i am asking is because my on-premise server only accepts request from whitelisted IP address and therefore we need a static ip address from request coming from Azure API management.

Comment: I think you should consider hosting your API apps on cloud services or VMs, and use Reserved IP Addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure api management shows a fixed ip address when you create the service.

We use this for the same scenario and we see all traffic from this ip.

Not much background info on it but this: https://www.nimbo.com/blog/azure-api-management-service-high-availability-disaster-recovery-backup-restore/
It is

Here the Faq on that
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq#is-the-api-management-gateway-ip-address-constant-can-i-use-it-in-firewall-rules

Comment: Thanks, i've verified it too with MS support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in all tiers of API Management, the IP address of the gateway remains static for its lifetime.

Comment: With the exception of the consumption tier. The consumption tier is dynamically hosted thus don't have a stable IP address.