# What is the up adress range for consumption based Azure api management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We have some on-prem servers accessing an Azure api management service in the West Europe datacenter. The Api Management instance has consumption based pricing.

Where can I find the up addresses Azure api management because the servers should be locked down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Static IP address in Azure API management Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168597/static-ip-address-in-azure-api-management-service)

Comment: That question is asking the opposite to my question.

Comment: My bad, reverting...

Answer (score 0):

Each Azure APIM service has it's own set of IP addresses. They're visible in service overview page in Azure Portal and in service properties page. Addresses are guaranteed to stay the same unless service is deleted or VNET joined/unjoined.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case with this instance. Could it be that it's consumption based pricing?

Comment: Oh, for consumption there is no guarantee on any fixed IP address.

Comment: So when we want to open our firewall outbound for a machine to be able to call an api service, do we need to open 1.1.1.1-255.255.255.255?

Comment: Which will open it to whole internet, yes. As of this moment there is no way to have a predictable set of IP addresses for consumption APIM service, only dedicated tiers have that.